# Gradle error, failed to create directory

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

today jump into such problem when launching test class using roboelectric and junit:

```
Information:Gradle: Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug, :app:assembleDebugUnitTest]
Error:Gradle: failed to create directory 'E:\AndroidKotlin\FooApp\app\build\generated\source\r\debug\com\example\foo\fooapp'
Error:Gradle: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:
Error:Gradle: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
```

Maybe someone has meet such nasty thing earlier and would be so nice to help me ;) ? If u don't have any idea, please let me know how can I try finding it on my own. I already did clean project and rebuild :)

Comment: Without even a snippet of your Gradle script(s) who knows? Have you tried to see if that path exists, or is writable, or is otherwise problematic? Have you tried running Gradle with the info or debug flags?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68936311

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally managed to get rid of all unwanted stuff with AS option:

```
File -> Invalidate caches / Restart
```

Answer (score 17):

I've met this error with Android Studio 3.0RC.
How to solve:
open (ctrl+shift+N): `gradle.properties`
add line: `android.enableAapt2=false`

You may find something useful here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0.html

Comment: This is a good work around, but eventually AAPT will be deprecated and disabling AAPT2 won't be an option, so it is important to come up with a better solution

Comment: If you agree with @NicolásCarrasco please star this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68936311

Answer (score 2):

Found such a dependency, if the project and the environment (SDK, Android Studio) is on different disks (volumes), then there will be an error. This error occurs when the test starts.

Solution, move the project to the root of the disk on which the SDK and Android Studio is located, it's helped me.

Android Studio 3.0.1, compileSdkVersion 27, Windows 10

Comment: Is this on windows?

Comment: @user1712200 yes

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by changing the JDK version I was using:

1. Go to File -> Project Structure.
2. On the left side, click on SDK Location and go to JDK Location.
3. Change it to the **Embedded JDK** that comes with Android Studio.
4. Click on OK.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please confirm that you have selected app in run configuration.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**Under Android**

1) Open Gradle Scripts

2) Open gradle.properties

3) Add `android.enableAapt2=false`

Then click on `Sync Now` on top right corner it should be fine now

Answer (score 0):

Close and run Android Studio as root user `sudo /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio`