# Android resource linking failed : while Installing Android Studio 3.2 windows

Tags: android, android-studio

After downloading suitable platform getting below error 
please Help to solve it, my work Stopped

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  error: failed to create directory 'D:\Dinesh\Workspace\Olive\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\com\omegasoftware\olivepos'.

Command: C:\Users\Logictrix\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\8aef690a884376d94dfdaa4e64e2a926\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        D:\Bhavesh\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        D:\Dinesh\Workspace\Olive\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        D:\Dinesh\Workspace\Olive\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @D:\Dinesh\Workspace\Olive\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        D:\Dinesh\Workspace\Olive\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --proguard-main-dex\
        D:\Dinesh\Workspace\Olive\app\build\intermediates\legacy_multidex_aapt_derived_proguard_rules\debug\processDebugResources\manifest_keep.txt\
        --custom-package\
        com.omegasoftware.olivepos\
        -0\
        apk\
        --preferred-density\
        tvdpi\
        --output-text-symbols\
        D:\Dinesh\Workspace\Olive\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Comment: Tried this File -> Invalidate caches / Restart ?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46512990/gradle-error-failed-to-create-directory

Comment: Thanks sunny i removed  .android  than restarted studio and its works

Answer (score 0):

AAPT2 had issues when creating directories on different drives than the executable or the project. Try moving everything to C: or D: (gradle cache and your project), or you can use a newer version of AGP that calls an AAPT2 version that already has a fix for it (3.3.0-alpha13).